# How can I train Options Selects?

Tags: super-street-fighter-iv

This [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3053/super-street-fighter-iv-option-select-and-hit-confirm) explains what an Option Select (OS) is, but how can I actually train them? I know it is possible to go into training mode and use the dummy to record an OS, so I can test it with the 1st player char.

- Scenario 1: Get hit -> Option 1 gets executed
- Scenario 2: Backdash -> Option 2 gets executed

But it takes a lot of time and pressing menu buttons to see if the input of one OS was correct.

I struggle especially with executing combos right after the OS.

Example for Ryu: sweep, j.HK OS Tatsu cr.MP ... (rest of combo)

Comment: This thread on SRK has some hints: http://shoryuken.com/forum/index.php?threads/option-select-practise.141456/

Comment: @Wilerson Can you summarize the link and add it as an answer, then I will up vote you and if nothing better comes up I will accept your answer.

Comment: I might do that when I get some free time to train OSs myself. :P In the meanwhile, here's another helpful thread: http://shoryuken.com/forum/index.php?threads/sf4-game-mechanics-option-selects.141486/

Answer (score 1):

Particularly as you asked about Ryu, there is a good section in Air's guide that goes over this (link with timestamp:

).

In short, make your training mode OPPONENT the character you're testing the OS with, and record you doing the OS. Then take control of the character you're testing against and attempt variaous things to see if the OS comes out.

You can then do the opposite with the dummy recorded to randomly backdash/reversal/do nothing/whatever to test if the OS comes out as you do it.

Of course, both of these are inferior to simply having another human in training mode with you, but that is not an option available to everyone.

Comment: I agree that this is the way to see if you execute them properly, but I want to train them. It is very complicated to input the OS and switch to opponent. Thanks for the video though.